# How to create a dashboard on Grafana, for backend api?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, observability, grafana-tempo, grafana-mimir

I found this Grafana dashboard for backend api app, online, it only mentions what tech stacks it's used which are LGTM : Loki, Grafana, Tempo, Mimir.

[image]

I only started learning monitoring and observability with the above tech stack recently.
And I only knew some of Prometheus, Opentelemetry & Fluentbit, only enough to clean and send datas from backend app, to destinations data sources.

I really want to build a dashboard similar to the above. Especially the : Total Requests, Request Count, Request Average Duration & Percent of 5xx Requests.

Could someone please enlighten me of how to do so ? like what should I focus on ? what resources can I rely on ? what tutorial to watch ? do I use metrics or traces to build what I want ?